# ZipInputStream.read in ZipEntry

Tags: scala, zipinputstream

I am reading zip file using ZipInputStream. Zip file has 4 csv files. Some files are written completely, some are written partially. Please help me find the issue with below code. Is there any limit on reading buffer from ZipInputStream.read method?

```
val zis = new ZipInputStream(inputStream)
Stream.continually(zis.getNextEntry).takeWhile(_ != null).foreach { file =>
      if (!file.isDirectory && file.getName.endsWith(".csv")) {
        val buffer = new Array[Byte](file.getSize.toInt)
        zis.read(buffer)
        val fo = new FileOutputStream("c:\\temp\\input\\" + file.getName)
        fo.write(buffer)
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not `close`d/`flush`ed the files you attempted to write. It should be something like this (assuming Scala syntax, or is this Kotlin/Ceylon?):

```
    val fo = new FileOutputStream("c:\\temp\\input\\" + file.getName)
    try {
      fo.write(buffer)
    } finally {
      fo.close
    }
```

Also you should check the read count and read more if necessary, something like this:

```
var readBytes = 0
while (readBytes < buffer.length) {
  val r = zis.read(buffer, readBytes, buffer.length - readBytes)
  r match {
    case -1 => throw new IllegalStateException("Read terminated before reading everything")
    case _ => readBytes += r
  }
}
```

PS: In your example it seems to be less than required closing `}`s.